# Can I change the way a token matches from a previous "more" command?

Tags: antlr4

I have a somewhat complex grammar where I'm forced to use lexical modes. To exit one of my modes, I need to match a token which is semantically significant in the next mode. However, the `more` command doesn't seem to behave as I would expect. Here is a simplified grammar to illustrate:

FooLexer.g4

```
lexer grammar FooLexer;

IGNORE: [\r\n]+ -> skip;

FOO: 'foo' -> pushMode(FINDBAR);
BARFOO: 'barfoo';

mode FINDBAR;

EXIT: 'bar' -> more,popMode;
OOPS: [\r\n]+;
```

test.input

```
foobarfoo
```

Output from `grun FooLexer tokens -encoding utf-8 -tokens test.input`:

```
[@0,0:2='foo',<'foo'>,1:0]
[@1,3:8='barfoo',<'foo'>,1:3]
[@2,9:9='\n',<OOPS>,1:9]
[@3,10:9='<EOF>',<EOF>,2:0]
```

I would like to match `BARFOO` instead of `FOO` when re-entering the default mode. Currently, I match `FOO` with the content "barfoo".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given,

> I need to match a token which is semantically significant in the next
>   mode.

try this --

```
FOO: 'foo' -> pushMode(FINDBAR);
BARFOO: 'barfoo';

mode FINDBAR;
  EXIT: 'barfoo' -> type(BARFOO),popMode;
  OOPS: [\r\n]+;
```

to emit the desired `BARFOO` token on exit.

---

Nothing equivalent can be achieved using `more`, since the `more` attribute cannot alter what is matched by any rule.  It only accumulates the text that was matched (and consumed) for inclusion into whatever next token is actually emitted (the next un-more'd token).

Accordingly, the `EXIT` rule does not produce a token.  The `EXIT` matched text is accumulated into the text of the `FOO` token `[@1,3:8='barfoo',<'foo'>,1:3]`

Comment: Unfortunately for my specific example, I have multiple modes (thus different semantic meanings) so I'll need to rethink how I am approaching the grammar. Your answer helps though, thank you!